# CSS dotted elements effect

Tags: css

I've setup a list where each list element contains two container: a `title` and a `description` container. What I need is to show dots at the bottom of each line.

It's working fine in Chrome and Safari. But unfortunately it doesn't work in firefox.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWa8R/)

Any suggestions on how to make this also work in firefox?

```
ul.basic {
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.basic li {
  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
}

ul.basic li .title, ul.basic li .description {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul.basic li .title {
  color: #999;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

ul.basic li .title span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul.basic li .title:after {
  content: '....................................................................... .......................................................................................................................................... ....................................................................................................................................... .............................................................................................................................................................................................';
  position: absolute;
  width: 300%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

ul.basic li .description {
  padding-left: 2px;
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: as a sidenote maybe a `<dt><dd>` structure could be semantically better

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898062/turning-an-unordered-list-into-a-table-of-contents

Comment: looks like FF doesn't understand `overflow` **in this case**, so weird, **but** not surprised, I'm so familiar with almost problems involving FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use an image to display the desired result properly in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 behaviour really different between FF and CHrome. Aniway why don't just use a

```
border-bottom: 1px dotted;
```

as css rule for css `.description` ? (also for `.title` if you need)

Comment: How to handle the case if `title` has multiple lines? With `border-bottom` there would be just one line of dots.

Comment: white-space:nowrap; to not let them on multiple lines. If you can't, a background image properly designed would be much better

Comment: dinamically pure css you can just text-decoration:underline; sadly not dotted.